# How to check the workflow initiator is a member of a specific group in Alfresco?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

The objective was to find out the workflow starter does the member of a specific group.
First, I need to get the member list inside a group.

A simple javascript that get the list of member inside a group, but it failed:

```
<scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Script Task" scriptFormat="javascript" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
<script>var node = people.getGroup("GROUP_Marketing");

    if(node) {
        logger.log("Marketing member list: " + people.getMembers(node));         
    }

</script>
</scriptTask>
```

And I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: problem evaluating script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "people" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

So, may I know the correct method to determine the workflow starter does exist the member of a specific group?

Comment: add some more code.I want to see where you are writing scriptTask.

Answer (score -1):

> The clean way would be to add an interceptor on the WorkflowService.
>   Intercept the result of the methods you need. At the very least "getDefinitions()". Possibly others too.

Complete post available here : https://forums.alfresco.com/comment/155580#comment-155580